# Concat in postgres pgjwt resulting in error

Tags: string, postgresql, string-concatenation

I am trying to use the [pgjwt function](https://github.com/michelp/pgjwt) but I get strange results when I concat text. Can someone explain what is going on here.

```
select sign ('"{foo": "bar"}', 'secret', 'HS512'); -- Works fine
select sign ('"{foo": "bar"}', 'secret', 'HS' || '512'); -- Works fine
select sign ('"{foo": "bar"}', 'sec' || 'ret', 'HS512'); -- Works fine
select sign ('"{fo' || 'o": "bar"}', 'secret', 'HS512'); -- Error
select sign ('"{foo":' || ' "bar"}', 'secret', 'HS512'); -- Error
select sign ('"{foo": "b' || 'ar"}', 'secret', 'HS512'); -- Error
select sign ('{}', 'sec' || 'ret', 'HS512'); -- Works fine
select sign ('{' || '}', 'sec' || 'ret', 'HS512'); -- Error
```

The error I get is:

```
ERROR: function sign (text, unknown, unknown) does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are splitting the JSON object into two strings of type `text` using the concatenation.

A cast afterwards should do the job, I believe:

```
select sign (('"{foo":' || ' "bar"}')::json, 'secret', 'HS512');
```