# PGJWT sign function call returning null

Tags: postgresql, error-handling, jwt

Following up after another question regarding how to [Concat in postgres pgjwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66364141/concat-in-postgres-pgjwt-resulting-in-error/66364208#66364208), pgjwt's `sign (...)` function appears to be returning a valid result when I store into `text` but returning `null` when I store into a `domain` but I can't tell why. I have set up two small versions of my code, one returning `text` and one returning a `domain` which is a `text` but with a `not null` constraint to support my conclusion. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix.

**Minimum Working Example:**

```
create domain jwt_token_type as text not null;

create or replace function login_user__works (p_token text)
returns text as
$$
declare
    v_token text;
begin
    select
        sign
    from
        sign(('{"username": "", "creation_timestamp":"' || (select extract (epoch from now ())) || '"}')::json, 'ojbIrZHDD1bJuuA5zjICKdWrziWzh5oF9MtTP2ctcEOlz8DEHArhqOvrMhgtpzxyySCybGh0mYXqrc052ztrSpzjmfXDnXSQhZ5ZbL6yXsfupWFHdockgINeBfIPP0U8OH4YR9bmNQlEsr8CN8rQ6QwKP4JvN9LDzOjlWQUisTvGLwjGgbn5hyOUoi3GgDZYV4aTAB2h2Ew125TKsbl5R4NAxuF1ZlitDjkW9MvEc5gkzIifSKBn6J1p1Pb2Zvcv', 'HS512')
    into
        v_token;

    return v_token;
end
$$ language 'plpgsql';

create or replace function login_user__fails (p_token jwt_token_type)
returns jwt_token_type as
$$
declare
    v_token jwt_token_type;
begin
    select
        sign
    from
        sign(('{"username": "", "creation_timestamp":"' || (select extract (epoch from now ())) || '"}')::json, 'ojbIrZHDD1bJuuA5zjICKdWrziWzh5oF9MtTP2ctcEOlz8DEHArhqOvrMhgtpzxyySCybGh0mYXqrc052ztrSpzjmfXDnXSQhZ5ZbL6yXsfupWFHdockgINeBfIPP0U8OH4YR9bmNQlEsr8CN8rQ6QwKP4JvN9LDzOjlWQUisTvGLwjGgbn5hyOUoi3GgDZYV4aTAB2h2Ew125TKsbl5R4NAxuF1ZlitDjkW9MvEc5gkzIifSKBn6J1p1Pb2Zvcv', 'HS512')
    into
        v_token;

    return v_token;
end
$$ language 'plpgsql';

select login_user__works ('Hello World'); -- Works and displays output
select login_user__fails ('Hello World'); -- Fails with the below error
```

**Error:**

```
psql:test.sql:38: ERROR:  domain jwt_token_type does not allow null values
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function login_user__fails(jwt_token_type) line 4 during statement block local variable initialization
```

**Note:**

The secret value is randomly generated so no security issues.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if you create a `domain` with a `not null` constraint then you can't only declare a variable of it's type but you must also initialize it to something. I fixed it by changed the declare statement like so:

```
create domain jwt_token_type as text not null;

create or replace function login_user__works (p_token text)
returns text as
$$
declare
    v_token text;
begin
    select
        sign
    from
        sign(('{"username": "", "creation_timestamp":"' || (select extract (epoch from now ())) || '"}')::json, 'ojbIrZHDD1bJuuA5zjICKdWrziWzh5oF9MtTP2ctcEOlz8DEHArhqOvrMhgtpzxyySCybGh0mYXqrc052ztrSpzjmfXDnXSQhZ5ZbL6yXsfupWFHdockgINeBfIPP0U8OH4YR9bmNQlEsr8CN8rQ6QwKP4JvN9LDzOjlWQUisTvGLwjGgbn5hyOUoi3GgDZYV4aTAB2h2Ew125TKsbl5R4NAxuF1ZlitDjkW9MvEc5gkzIifSKBn6J1p1Pb2Zvcv', 'HS512')
    into
        v_token;

    return v_token;
end
$$ language 'plpgsql';

create or replace function login_user__fails (p_token jwt_token_type)
returns jwt_token_type as
$$
declare
    v_token jwt_token_type := ''; -- Initialize the variable
begin
    select
        sign
    from
        sign(('{"username": "", "creation_timestamp":"' || (select extract (epoch from now ())) || '"}')::json, 'ojbIrZHDD1bJuuA5zjICKdWrziWzh5oF9MtTP2ctcEOlz8DEHArhqOvrMhgtpzxyySCybGh0mYXqrc052ztrSpzjmfXDnXSQhZ5ZbL6yXsfupWFHdockgINeBfIPP0U8OH4YR9bmNQlEsr8CN8rQ6QwKP4JvN9LDzOjlWQUisTvGLwjGgbn5hyOUoi3GgDZYV4aTAB2h2Ew125TKsbl5R4NAxuF1ZlitDjkW9MvEc5gkzIifSKBn6J1p1Pb2Zvcv', 'HS512')
    into
        v_token;

    return v_token;
end
$$ language 'plpgsql';

select login_user__works ('Hello World'); -- Works and displays output
select login_user__fails ('Hello World'); -- Now it works after intialization
```